# c language Segmentation fault

Tags: c

This is the code.
i don't know how to fix that.
this program is about I/O file and convert each line form hex to bin.
i got the right outcome for the first, then segmentation fault.
can anyone point out what's wrong of that
thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


FILE *file, *newFile;

char output[13];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    newFile = fopen("output.txt","wa+");
    char binary1[50];
    char first[2], secondDigit[2], third[2], last[2];
    char scr[5];
    char binary[16][5] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101","0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110","1111"};
    char digits [] = "0123456789abcdef";

    while(fgets(scr, 5, file) && scr[5] != EOF) {
        char res[100];
        int p = 0;
        int value =0;
        while(scr[p])
        {
            const char * v = strchr(digits, tolower(scr[p]));

            if(v[0]>96){
                value=v[0]-87;
            }
            else{
                value=v[0]-48;
            }
            if (v){
                strcat(res, binary[value]);
            }
            p++;
        }
        printf("Res:%s\n", res);
    }       
    fclose(newFile);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The correct loop is `while(fgets(scr, 5, file) != NULL)`

Comment: You should check if `value` is not out of the bound of `binary` valgrind will highlight the issue for you

Comment: i added that but still segmentation fault

Comment: You dereference `v` before checking if `strchr()` returned NULL or not.

Comment: how to  dereference `v`

Comment: Please show the first few lines of the file you are reading. And what is `tolower`? And what are the magic numbers `87` and `48`? The "wa+" mode doesn't exist. And you don't check the return values of `fopen`, if `fopen` returns `NULL` the file could not be opened and then it's pointless to proceed..

Comment: `c language Segmentation fault`.. can you please choose  a better title?

Comment: And one more thing: `strchr` can return `NULL` and you don't check for this. And there are many more errors. I suggest you learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: One of several problems is that you want to check `if (v)` *before* you refer to `v[0]`.  If `v` is `NULL`, `v[0]` (on your machine and OS) will cause a segmentation fault. That’s the dereferencing people were talking about. Another potential cause is `binary[value]` if `value` is out-of-bounds for the array.

Comment: `fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
       stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
       EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
       A  terminating  null  byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in
       the buffer.`
you should define `scr` as one more length longer and try to compare that last bit with null.

Comment: `scr[5]` is one beyond the end of the `scr` array in `while(fgets(scr, 5, file) && scr[5] != EOF)`. The valid indexes for `scr` are `0-4`. Attempting to access `scr[5]` invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`  for the definition of `tolower()`

Comment: the variables: `last` `third` `secondDigit` `first` and `binary1` are not used, so should be eliminated.

Comment: code should never access beyone `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter(s) was actually entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you get to the end of a line `scr[p]` is `\n` and the behaviour of `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);` is that it returns `NULL` when it doesn't find any occurrence of `c` in the string `s`.

The segmentation fault is because due to `v` being `NULL` when you try to dereference it.

You should check when `v` is `NULL` and handle it accordingly.

This is also a problem when do `file = fopen(argv[1],"r");` if the file doesn't exist then the variable `file` will be `NULL` causing a segmentation fault when you call `fgets(scr, 5, file)`.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains several problems:

- does not check for error conditions
- does not ever write to 'output.txt'
- contains lots of unused variables
- accesses beyond 'argv[0]' without first checking 'argc' to assure the parameter was actually typed by the user.
- does not remove possible newline sequence from end of input buffer
- would be a lot more readable if followed the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
- would be a lot more readable if used ascii char literals rather than numbers
- would be a lot more readable if code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case default) were separated via a single blank line.
- does not check that the 'current' character read is in the range 0...9 and a...f inclusive
- does not allow for possible 'res[]' buffer overflow.

and now the proposed code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // FILE, fopen(), fclose(), fgets(), fprintf(), fprint(), perror(), puts()
#include <string.h>  // strchr()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>   // tolower()


#define MAX_INPUT_LEN  5


const char binary[][ MAX_INPUT_LEN ] =
{
    "0000",
    "0001",
    "0010",
    "0011",
    "0100",
    "0101",
    "0110",
    "0111",
    "1000",
    "1001",
    "1010",
    "1011",
    "1100",
    "1101",
    "1110",
    "1111"
};

const char digits [] = "0123456789abcdef";


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if( 2 != argc )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s inputFileName\n", argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, correct number of arguments

    FILE *fpin = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if( !fpin )
    {
        perror( "fopen for read of input file failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    //FILE *fpout = fopen("output.txt","wa+");
    //if( !fpout )
    //{
    //    perror( "fopen for output.txt for write failed" );
    //    fclose( fpin );   // cleanup
    //    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    //}

    // implied else, fopen successful

    //char binary1[50];
    //char first[2], secondDigit[2], third[2], last[2];

    // plus 2 to allow for possible newline and terminating NUL byte
    char scr[ MAX_INPUT_LEN+2 ];


    while( fgets(scr,  MAX_INPUT_LEN+2, fpin) )
    {
        // remove possible newline
        char *newline = strchr( scr, '\n' );
        if( newline )
        {
            *newline = '\0';
        }

        int value = 0;

        for( size_t i=0; scr[i]; i++ )
        {
            int temp = tolower(scr[i]);
            const char * v = strchr(digits, temp);
            if( !v )
            {
                printf( "non 'digit' in input line\n");
                continue;
            }

            if(v[0]>= 'a')
            {
                value= v[0] - 'a' + 10;  // result is 10...15
            }

            else
            {
                value= v[0] - '0'; // result is 0...9
            }

            printf( "%s", binary[value]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    fclose( fpin );
    //fclose( fpout );
    return 0;
}
```